# Order of items in imenu

Tags: imenu

When I create an `imenu` with the help of the lisp snippet

```el
(defun my-index-function ()
  (message "Running `my-index-function'.")
  '(("1" . 1) ("1.1" ("1.1.1" . 2) ("1.1.2" . 3) ("1.1.3" . 4)) ("1.2" . 5)))
(setq imenu-create-index-function #'my-index-function)
(imenu-add-to-menubar "index menu")
```

I get an *index menu* with the items

- 1.1

  - 1.1.1
  - 1.1.2
  - 1.1.3
- 1
- 1.2

But this does not correspond to the wanted order of elements in the list returned by `my-index-function` – which is

- 1
- 1.1

  - 1.1.1
  - 1.1.2
  - 1.1.3
- 1.2

What am I missing? Is this some special feature of `imenu` or is it just a bug?
How can I get the wanted order in the *index menu*?

**`emacs-version`**: **GNU Emacs 25.1.1**

---

The real application is adding `imenu`-support to `reftex`.
Below you find the first rough test version which works for a single-LaTeX-source  buffer.

```el
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; imenu-support for reftex

(require 'imenu)

(unless (fboundp #'substring-no-indent)
  (defun substring-no-indent (str)
    "Return STR without its leading whitespace."
    (substring str (string-match "[^[:space:]]" str))))

(defun reftex-outline-tree-recursive (docstruct &optional level)
  "Returns a cons of a tree generated from DOCSTRUCT and the rest of DOCSTRUCT to be processed.
The initial DOCSTRUCT should be the value of the symbol stored at `reftex-docstruct-symbol'."
  (unless (equal (caar docstruct) 'toc)
    (setq docstruct (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (entry)
                    (equal (car entry) 'toc))
                      docstruct)))
  (unless level
    (setq level (nth 5 (car docstruct))))
  (let (tree)
    (cl-block nil
      (while docstruct
    (let* ((entry (car docstruct))
           (entry-level (nth 5 entry))
           (next-entry (car-safe (cdr docstruct)))
           (next-entry-level (nth 5 next-entry))
           leaf)
      (cond
       ((or (null (numberp entry-level))
        (< entry-level level))
        (cl-return))
       ((and (numberp next-entry-level) (> next-entry-level entry-level))
        (cl-multiple-value-setq (leaf docstruct) (reftex-outline-tree-recursive (cdr docstruct)))
        (setq leaf (cons (cons "-\"-" (car (last entry))) leaf)) ; prepend the section itself
        (setq tree (cons (cons (substring-no-indent (nth 2 entry)) leaf) tree)))
       (t ; entry-level == level
        (setq tree (cons (cons (substring-no-indent (nth 2 entry)) (car (last entry))) tree)
          docstruct (cdr docstruct)))))))
    (list (nreverse tree) docstruct)))

(defun reftex-outline-tree (docstruct)
  "Returns the toc tree generated from DOCSTRUCT as stored as value of the symbol stored at `reftex-docstruct-symbol'."
  (let (subtree tree)
    (while docstruct
      (cl-multiple-value-setq (subtree docstruct) (reftex-outline-tree-recursive docstruct))
      (setq tree (append tree subtree)))
    tree))

(defcustom reftex-outline-flat-default nil
  "The index menu \"TeX Outline\" has a flat structure if this option is true."
  :group 'reftex-table-of-contents-browser
  :type 'boolean)

(defvar reftex-outline-flat reftex-outline-flat-default
  "The index menu \"TeX Outline\" has a flat structure if this option is true.
The default is read from `reftex-outline-flat-default'.")

(defun reftex-outline ()
  "Add the index of the TeX document."
  (interactive)
  (reftex-access-scan-info t)
  (let ((docstruct (cl-remove-if-not (lambda (entry)
                       (equal (car entry) 'toc))
                     (symbol-value reftex-docstruct-symbol))))
    (if reftex-outline-flat
    (mapcar (lambda (item)
          (cons (format "%s" (nth 2 item))
            (car (last item))))
        docstruct)
      (reftex-outline-tree docstruct))))

(defun reftex-toggle-outline-flat (&optional force)
  "Toggle `reftex-outline-flat'.
With prefix arg > 0 switch flat outline on. With prefix arg <= 0 switch it off."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (numberp force)
      (setq reftex-outline-flat (> force 0))
    (setq reftex-outline-flat (null reftex-outline-flat))))

(defun reftex-imenu-update-advice (&rest args)
  "Add \"Flat Outline\" to \"TeX Outline\" menu."
  (ignore args)
  (when (and imenu--index-alist reftex-docstruct-symbol)
    (easy-menu-add-item imenu--menubar-keymap nil ["Flat Outline" (progn (reftex-toggle-outline-flat) (imenu--menubar-select '("*Rescan*" . -99))) :style toggle :selected reftex-outline-flat] "*Rescan*")))

(defun reftex-outline-imenu-enable ()
  "Enable imenu in the current TeX buffer."
  (interactive)
  (setq-local imenu-create-index-function
          #'reftex-outline)
  (imenu-add-to-menubar "TeX Outline")
  (advice-add #'imenu-update-menubar :after #'reftex-imenu-update-advice))

(defun reftex-outline-imenu-disable ()
  "Disable imenu in the current PDF buffer."
  (interactive)
  (setq-local imenu-create-index-function nil)
  (local-set-key [menu-bar index] nil))
```

This gives the index entry `-"-` for the start of the first sub-section after the first sub-sub-section for the following example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{1}
\subsection{11}
\subsubsection{111}
\subsubsection{112}
\subsection{12}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

I know about [`imenu-add-menubar-index`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LaTeX) but I don't like the splitting of the table of contents into groups. I like better if `imenu` creates sub-menus for subsections.

Comment: I had to solve a similar problem in [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/blob/master/lisp/pdf-outline.el#L538).

Comment: @politza Thanks a lot. I almost copied your solution and added it at the end of the question. I did not answer my own question to give you the opportunity to write a short answer. You can just combine your comment text with a pointer to the answer at the end of the question. I would accept and upvote your answer. Thanks again. By the way, pdf-tools is cool! (I got it running under Cygwin.)

Comment: @politza Have you considered to issue a feature-request at `emacs-devel@gnu.org` to make the sorting in `imenu` optional?

Comment: No, I haven't. And please feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: @politza Okay. Then I move the solution from the question to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of user poliza provided the following solution based on
[`pdf-outline--imenu--split-menu`](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/blob/master/lisp/pdf-outline.el#L554) from `pdf-tools`.

```el
;; See http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31791/order-of-items-in-imenu?noredirect=1#comment48799_31791
(advice-add #'imenu--split-menu :around #'reftex-outline-imenu--split-menu)

(defun reftex-outline-imenu--split-menu (oldfun menulist title)
  "Replacement function for `imenu--split-menu'.
This function does not move sub-menus to the top, therefore
keeping the original outline order of the document.  Also it does
not call `imenu-sort-function'."
  (if (reftex-outline-p)
      (let ((menulist (copy-sequence menulist))
        keep-at-top)
    (if (memq imenu--rescan-item menulist)
        (setq keep-at-top (list imenu--rescan-item)
          menulist (delq imenu--rescan-item menulist)))
    (if (> (length menulist) imenu-max-items)
        (setq menulist
          (mapcar
           (lambda (menu)
             (cons (format "From: %s" (caar menu)) menu))
           (imenu--split menulist imenu-max-items))))
    (cons title
          (nconc (nreverse keep-at-top) menulist)))
    (funcall oldfun menulist title)))
```

Comment: If this solves your problem, could you accept the answer, please?